# How groupby unique value ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to groupby this dataframe with unique values for priority and Alias column to create a latex report:

```
Alias         Number    Duration(h)   priority
A             23834     8111.130497   120
B             16453     6773.243598   120
C             15988     8347.042753   120
A             19        113.475702    139
B             16        113.476042    139
```

So I tried:

```
df = df.groupby(['priority', 'Alias'])
df
```

The terminal return:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000002377285CA00>
```

The expected result:

```
priority    Alias    Number    Duration(h)
120         A        23834     8111.130497
            B        16453     6773.243598
            C        15988     8347.042753
139         A        19        113.475702
            B        16        113.476042
```

I don't understand why the terminal return this... Thanks for your time !

Comment: I think you need `df.set_index(['priority', 'Alias'])` not groupby

Comment: why there is a shift between the name of the columns ?

Comment: because you've created an index, if you don't care for it and only want a dataframe for cosmetic purposes, try `df['priority'] = df['priority'].mask(df['priority'].duplicated()).fillna('');print( df[['priority','Alias','Number','Duration(h)']])`

Comment: @Manakin Just another question, if I want to have the three first of each priority; so I can use head(3) but where I can add it ?

Comment: IIUC `df.groupby(...).head(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Your data are already grouped by priority and alias because every combination of values for this 2 columns is unique at your dataset. It's just a matter of visualize it better and i think the `set_index()` above recommended is the correct answer.
You can also bring priority column in front of alias.